# Issues with pure CSS3 Multi Level Menu and Jquery Slider

Tags: jquery, css, menu, slider

I am new to this site and hoping that someone can assist me with an annoying problem that I am having.

The Page in question is located at www.raulgonzalez.com/menu.php.

This is an HTML5 and CSS3 page that is also using a simple JQuery Image Slider.

As you can see the CSS3 Menu appears in two places to illustrate the problem.
1) Above the JQuery Slider
2) Below the JQuery Slider

If you click on the "About" Menu Below the JQuery Slider, the menu expands without any problems and overlays the bottom part of the page.

Now, If you click on the "About" Menu above the JQuery Slider, the menu DOES NOT fully expand.

I would prefer to see the CSS3 Menu above the JQuery Slider but, I have not been able to figure out how to fix this.  Until then, I will live the CSS3 Menu below.

Would greatly appreciate any ideas, suggestions, or solutions that others can provide.

Sincerely

Raul Gonzalez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply assign the menu a **z-index** in your css, which will put it "above" (ie in the z direction) everything else:

```
ul.main-navigation {
  z-index: 100;
}
```

**Edit**: I would swear that worked yesterday when I tried it using the Inspector!  Ok, there are a lot of overlapping rules here... try this instead (works for me in Firefox and Chrome):

```
ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: #000099;
  z-index:100;
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the update but unless I have done something wrong, this change does not seem to fix my issue.  Please visit www.raulgonzalez.com/menu.php and view source code line 113-115.  i still have the same issue.   Thanks in advance Raul Gonzalez

Comment: Gary Hasler, please reference my comments. Thanks

Comment: Gary Hasler that worked.  I tried it on Safari and Internet Explorer and it worked, Looks like I have all the major browsers covered.  Thank you very much.  I have HTML5 down pad but CSS3 is still a bit of a challenge for me. Can you recommend a course or book that I can look into?

Comment: Z-index is actually css2; it's been around for ages.  There are lots of web sites which review the new css 3 features...eg: http://www.css3.info/preview/  and [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/01/19/53-css-techniques-you-couldnt-live-without/) (unfortunately I never bookmarked the ones I really liked!).